# I need to get an id on a correspondence column a maximum of another column

Tags: t-sql

```
ContractId  ParentId    VersionNo
32388437    NULL         0
32388439    2884617      1
32617644    2884617      2
33572734    2884617      3
```

I'm just starting out in the SQL. 
I need a query to return  ContractId of the max of column versionNo from a specific table. Can u help me?

```
SELECT  MAX(VersionNo),ISNULL(ParentId,ContractId) 
FROM table1 
WHERE ParentId=ParentId GROUP by  ISNULL(ParentId,ContractId)
```

that query does not return lines that column VersionNo have Null

Comment: Why the ParentId=ParentId?  There is no VersionNo have Null in that data.

Comment: Jayvee`s answer is ok .

Comment: Jayvee`s answer does not have a check mark

Comment: Frisbee... that measns? :)

Answer (score 2):

Another answer using a CTE

```
WITH max_cte AS 
( SELECT t.ContractId
       , t.ParentId
       , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.ParentId ORDER BY t.VersionNo DESC) AS 'MaxVersion'
    FROM table1 AS t
)
SELECT ContractId
     , ParentId
  FROM max_cte 
 WHERE MaxVersion = 1;
```

Comment: not working... u put in where condition MaxVersio=1.

Comment: How do you mean it is not working? The query returns the correct result, although naming the column MaxVersion could be misleading. MaxVersion will always be 1 for the row with the largest VersionNo value. Perhaps I should have called it Sort, Order or Sequence?

Answer (score 1):

```
select  ParentId,ContractId,VersionNo 
from
( 
select ParentId,ContractId,VersionNo, max(VersionNo) Over(partition by ParentId) maxvers
from table1
) x
where VersionNo=maxvers
```

Comment: Is a Numeric. not ok this solution. Are same cases when i have a ContractId with VersionNo '0' that have ParentID 'Null'. Is ok to have VersionNo 0. All i need is that i select from a specific  table lines : ContractId that have in Column VersionNo the maximum value. In my first example the right answer is 33572734    2884617      3. I can`t find the right query to return that info...

Comment: I need ContractID that have the maximum value in VersionNo.

Comment: try this one and let me know if it's more like what you are looking for

Comment: i can`t see any query :(

Comment: Thank you. Works great !

Answer (score 0):

```
select  ISNULL(ParentId,ContractId)--,ContractId,VersionNo 
from
( 
select ParentId,ContractId,VersionNo, max(VersionNo) Over(partition by ParentId) maxvers, EndDate
from table1
) x
where  VersionNo=maxvers
```

Based on the [answer by Jayvee](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35862707).